# $locate -S command is not working in Ubuntu 20.04 (plocate is installed, all other commands work fine)

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-20.04

I am facing this error while running 'locate -S' command. Is this only executable in mlocate?

My error:

```
user@Ubuntu:~$ locate -S

locate: invalid option -- 'S'
```

Is there an alternate command, I can use?

Expected output:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ locate -S
Database /var/lib/plocate/plocate.db:
    16,009 directories
    144,928 files
    7,826,392 bytes in file names
    4,234,872 bytes used to store database
```

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

I basically have the same issue on my system, unfortunately no solution yet. Other "locate"-commands are working, but not the "locate -S".
I found different sources where they advice for a reinstallation of locate-command or an update of the database via:

sudo updatedb

Updating the database did not help on my system. I am even not sure, if the database exists already. At least I could not find the dedicated file yet. Should be a file with the name:

mlocate.db

and might be located here:

/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db

Comment: I now also tried to remove the package via:

sudo apt remove locate

Then reinstalling and even upgrading them with:

sudo apt install locate
sudo apt upgrade locate

Still it's not working on my side.

Comment: Both you and OP are barking up the wrong tree. This Q belongs to superuser.com or perhaps askubuntu.com, SO is about programming not about user issues.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).